# Benefits of learning scheme?

Tags: scheme

I've just started one of my courses, as classes just began 2 weeks ago, and we are learning Scheme right now in one for I assume some reason later on, but so far from what he is teaching is basically how to write in scheme.  As I sit here trying to stay awake I'm just trying to grasp why I would want to know this, and why anyone uses it.  What does it excel at?  Next week I plan to ask him, whats the goal to learn here other than just how to write stuff in scheme.

Comment: BTW, I think it's very rich that you have a username of "chicken" and are questioning the value of Scheme! http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/

Comment: It's almost exactly 4 years since you started learning Scheme. I'm curious what you think the benefits of learning it were looking back.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a functional programming language and will do well broaden your experience.

Even if you don't use it in the real world doesn't mean it doesn't have any value.  It will help you master things like recursion and help to force you to think of problems in different ways than you normally would.

I *wish* my school forced us to learn a functional programming language.

Answer (score 9):

Languages like LISP (and the very closely related Scheme) are to programming what Latin is to English.

You may never speak Latin a day in your normal life again after taking a course, but simply learning a language like Latin will improve your ability to use English.

The same is true for Scheme.

Answer (score 9):

I see all these people here saying that while they would never actually use Scheme again it's nevertheless been a worthwhile language to learn because it forces a certain way of thinking. While this can be true, I would hope that you would learn Scheme because you eventually will find it useful and not simply as an exercise in learning.

Though it's not blazingly fast like a compiled language, nor is it particularly useful at serving websites or parsing text, I've found that Scheme (and other lisps by extension) has no parallel when it comes to simplicity, elegance, and powerful functional manipulation of complex data structures. To be honest, I think in Scheme. It's the language I solve problems in. Don't give up on or merely tolerate Scheme - give it a chance and it won't disappoint you.

By the way, the best IDE for Scheme is [DrScheme](http://www.drscheme.org/), and it contains language extensions to do anything you can do in another language, and if you find something it can't you can just use the C FFI and write it yourself.

Comment: I would assume scheme would be well suited to parse text actually, no?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to keep an **open mind** when learning.  Most of the time in school we don't fully comprehend what/why we are learning a particular subject.  But as I've experienced about a million times in life, it turns out to be very useful and at the very least being aware of it helps you.  Scheme, believe it or not, will make you a better programmer.

Answer (score 6):

Some people say Scheme's greatest strength is as a teaching language. While it is very beneficial to learn functional programming (it's an entirely new way of thinking) another benefit in learning scheme is that it is also "pure". Sure it can't do a ton of stuff like java, but that's also what's great about it, it's a language made entirely of parentheses, alphanumeric characters, and a mere handful other punctuations.

In my intro course, we are taught Java, and I see lots of my friends struggling with 'public static void main' even though that's not the point of the program and how the profs have no choice but to 'handwave' it until they're more advanced. You don't see that in Scheme.

If you really want to learn what Scheme can do in a piece of cake that is really hard to implement in languages like Java, I suggest looking at this: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3

This is probably the best book written on Scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Scheme was used by NASA to program some of the Mars rovers. It's usage in the marketplace is pretty specific, but like I'm sure your teachers are telling you, the things you learn in Scheme will carry over to programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to get caught up on details like the parenthesis, and car/cdr.  Most of what you're learning translates to other languages in one way or another.  Don't worry about whether or not you can take Scheme to the market place, chances are you'll be learning some other more marketable languages in other classes.  What you are learning here is more important.

If you are learning scheme, you can learn all about how object systems are implemented (hint: an object system isn't always about a type that has methods and instance variables bound to it...).  While this kind of knowledge won't help in 95% of your daily work, for 5% of your work you will depend on that knowledge.

Additionally, you can learn about completely different styles of computation, such as streams/lazy evaluation, or even logic programming.  You could also learn more about how computer programs in general are interpreted; from the basics in how program code is evaluated, to more deeper aspects like making your own interpreter and compiler).  Knowing this kind of information is what separates a good programmer from a great programmer.

Scheme is not really a Functional language, it's more method agnostic then that.  Perhaps more to the point, Scheme is an excellent language to choose if you want to explore with different methods of computation.  As an example, a highly parallel functional language "Termite" was built on top of Scheme.

In short, the point in learning scheme is so that you can learn the fundamentals of programming.

If you need some help in making programming in scheme more enjoyable, don't be afraid to ask.  A lot of programmers get hung up on (for instance) the parenthesis, when there are perfectly great ways to work with scheme source code that makes parenthesis something to cherish, rather then hate.  As an example, emacs with paredit-mode,some kind of scheme interaction mode and highlight-parenthesis-mode is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was when learning this we learned clisp right along with it. I couldn't keep the two strait to save my life.

What I did learn from them though was how to write better c and java code. This is simply because of the different programming style I learned. I have adapted more of the functional style into some of my programming and It has helped me in some cases.

I would never want to program in scheme or lisp again if I didn't have to, but I am glad that I at least did a little in them just to learn the different way to program.

Answer (score 1):

Functional languages like Scheme have great application to mathematics, artificial intelligence, linguistics, and other highly theoretical areas of computer science (machine learning, natural language processing, etc). This is due to the purity of functional programming languages, which have no side effects, as well as their ability to navigate higher-order procedures with ease. A strong knowledge of functional programming languages is critical for solving many of the questions which hover just beyond the frontier of computer science. As a bonus, you'll get great with higher-order procedures and recursion.

Comment: Scheme is not a pure functional language.

Comment: True, but if your use of Scheme is predominantly non-functional then you shouldn't be using Scheme. Anyone who learns Scheme without also gaining a solid understanding of functional programming hasn't successfully "learned" Scheme.